# How does works the destructuring array with generator functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I find this example and I was surprising the way that the eventually values of the generator are get from the generator. This is the code:

```
function* foo() {
  yield 'a';
  yield 'b';
  yield 'c';
}

const [...values] = foo();
```

Based on my understand of generators, i think that destructuring a generator execution is equivalent to:

```
const array = [];
for(const val of foo()) {
    array.push(val)
}
```

so, my question is: **It is this a valid approach to get the values of a generator function and what other ways exists for achieve this?**

Comment: That seems a'ight to me

Comment: "is this a valid approach?" -- [does it work? Yes? Then it's valid.](https://esfiddle.net/j2ruoocs/) "what other ways exist to achieve this?" Lots; likely that bit is too broad a question for SO.

Comment: It is valid, but IMHO less readable than `const values = [...foo()]` or even `const values = Array.from(foo())`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Creating an array from ES6 generator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43939821/218196)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **iteration** *(iterable & iterator)* **protocols** offer you an ocean of possibilities...

```js
function* foo() {
  yield 'a';
  yield 'b';
  yield 'c';
}

const [...values] = foo();

console.log(...values);
```

```js
function* foo() {
  yield 'a';
  yield 'b';
  yield 'c';
}

const [a, b, c] = foo();

console.log(a, b, c);
```

```js
function* foo() {
  yield 'a';
  yield 'b';
  yield 'c';
};

let values = [];

for (const str of foo()) {
  values.push(str);
}

console.log(values[0], values[1], values[2]);
```

```js
function* foo() {
  yield 'a';
  yield 'b';
  yield 'c';
}

const [a, b, ...values] = Array.from(foo());

console.log(a, b, values.toString());
```

```js
let foo = (function* () {
  yield 'a';
  yield 'b';
  yield 'c';
})();

console.log(foo.next().value, foo.next().value, foo.next().value);
```